# AngularJS: how to preprocess json data

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have created a factory to retrieve json data from my backend. Parts of the json data is heavily text-based and needs to convert line breaks into coupled `<p></p>` tags.

I tried to use this function to process the text in my view file.

```
function TextProcess(text) {
    var p_text = text.replace("/[\r\n]+/", "</p><p>")+"</p>";
    var finish_text = p_text.replace("/(?<=\s)\x20|\x20(?=\s)/", "&nbsp;");
    return(finish_text);
}
```

It is possible that this function has its own problem...(I'm very new to javascript)

Then in view, I tried:

```
<p>{{TextProcess(article.body)}}</p>
```

This line gets me nowhere.

Is what I am doing the right way to process text in AngularJS? I have no idea how to process Json data using AngularJS without the help of `ng-repeat`.

Please tell me what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this is using a custom filter to apply formatting to the text.

You will end up writing this in your template:

```
<span ng-bind-html-unsafe="text | customFilter"></span>
```

Here is the custom filter code (i named it 'fixup')

```
.filter('fixup', function () {

return function (input) {
    var txt = input.replace("/[\r\n]+/", "</p><p>") + "</p>";
    var out = txt.replace("/(?<=\s)\x20|\x20(?=\s)/", "&nbsp;");

  return out;
}
```

I created a fiddle, but the substitution isn't working so well, but it should give a solid starting point:
http://jsfiddle.net/aNp8M/2/

Comment: Thanks!!!! It worked. I changed my RegExp of course..this is how I wrote on my template. I'm not sure if this is the right way to do: <p ng-bind-html-unsafe="article.body | textProcess">{{article.body}}</p>

Comment: glad to help. please mark the question as the answer and/or vote it up.